# Smooth Scrolling within div overflow:hidden

Tags: jquery, scroll, overflow, hidden, smoothing

I want a div with the overflow:hidden property to be able to smooth scroll between anchors on a page I'm working on. I have tried a few jquery options, but none of which seem to work. I'm not sure if this is because the div is set to overflow:hidden or that the links to the anchors are outside of the said div.

Here is the css for the div that I would like the smooth scrolling to work within:

```
.container {
    height:400px;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    background: #FFF;
    overflow:hidden;
```

and the links are currently placed in the header as seen here:

```
<div class="header">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#aboutme"> <IMG class="header" src="Thumbs/about-me.gif" /></a></li>

    <li><a href="#education"> <IMG class="header" src="Thumbs/education.gif" /></a></li>
    <li><IMG class="headertitle" src="Thumbs/title.jpg" height="150" /></li>
    <li><a href="#employment" > <IMG class="header" src="Thumbs/employment.gif" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#otherskills" > <IMG class="header" src="Thumbs/other-skills.gif" /></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

finally, here are the contents of the .container div:

```
<div class="container">
  <span id="aboutme"></span>
  <div class="aboutme">
    about me
  </div>

  <span id="education"></span>
  <div class="education">
    education
  </div>

  <span id="employment"></span>
  <div class="employment">
    employment
  </div>

  <span id="otherskills"></span>
  <div class="otherskills">
    other skills
  </div>
```

I have tried implementing [this](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/) and other smooth scrolling techniques, but when I do, there is no smooth scrolling. Sorry if this is unclear, and if my coding is a complete mess, but any help would be positive.

Thanks, John

Comment: On SO, we expect the problem to be fully contained in the question, posts asking to look on your site and find the problem are condidered the breaking of SO netiquette. You should create as small as possible illustration of the problem, and list the attempted solutions with the description what was wrong with them.

Comment: Hi, sorry for not being clear! I have not posted here before.. I have updated the question and hopefully it's constructed more helpfully. Thanks!